# C Structure with char pointer type fail to insert value in a function

Tags: c, string, pointers, structure

This code compile fine with Codeblocks on Windows, and when I press 1 to run the function "Aggiungi" (Insert), I can only insert Name, Surname and the when I press Enter after Surname (so when I should insert Tel), it crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100

typedef struct rubrica
{
    char *nome;
    char *cognome;
    char *tel;
} rubrica;

void aggiungi(rubrica *contatto, int ncont);

int main(void)
{
    rubrica *contatto[MAX];
    int act, ncont=0;

    do
    {
        printf("1)AGGIUNGI\n");
        printf("2)VISUALIZZA\n");
        printf("0)ESCI\n");
        scanf("%d", &act);

        if(act==1)
        {
            aggiungi(*contatto, ncont);
            ncont++;
        }
    } while (act!=0);

    return 0;
}

void aggiungi(rubrica *contatto, int ncont)
{
    printf("\n________________\n");

    contatto[ncont].nome=malloc(21*sizeof(char*));
    printf("\nNome: ");
    scanf("%s", contatto[ncont].nome);

    contatto[ncont].cognome=malloc(21*sizeof(char*));
    printf("\nCognome: ");
    scanf("%s", contatto[ncont].cognome);

    contatto[ncont].tel=malloc(12*sizeof(char*));
    printf("\nTelefono: ");
    scanf("%s", contatto[ncont].tel);


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `rubrica *contatto[MAX];` --> `rubrica contatto[MAX];` ,Then  `aggiungi(*contatto, ncont);` --> `aggiungi(contatto, ncont);`

Comment: Major: `rubrica *contatto[MAX];` has no memory allocated to any of its pointer elements. Minor: `malloc(21*sizeof(char*))` should be `malloc(21*sizeof(char))`.

Comment: I changed `aggiungi(*contatto, ncont);` in `aggiungi(&contatto, ncont);
It seems to work, but I think I should create in the main a pointer that points to contatto[ncont] and then pass this pointer to the function. Would it be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see from declaration (`rubrica *contatto[MAX];`) `contatto` is array of pointers, but your code leads to to idea, that you need pointer to array or just array of structures (more likely).

So, my suggestion is to redesign you data declaration.

For example, try as follows:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100

typedef struct rubrica
{
    char *nome;
    char *cognome;
    char *tel;
} rubrica;

void aggiungi(rubrica *contatto, int ncont);

int main(void)
{
    rubrica contatto[MAX]; // array of items
    int act, ncont = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("1)AGGIUNGI\n");
        printf("2)VISUALIZZA\n");
        printf("0)ESCI\n");
        scanf("%d", &act);
        if (act == 1)
        {
            aggiungi(contatto, ncont); // contatto is used without *
            ncont++;
        }
    } while (act != 0);
    return 0;
}

void aggiungi(rubrica *contatto, int ncont) // here *contatto is instead of contatto []
{
    printf("\n________________\n");

    contatto[ncont].nome = malloc(21 * sizeof(char*));
    printf("\nNome: ");
    scanf("%s", contatto[ncont].nome);

    contatto[ncont].cognome = malloc(21 * sizeof(char*));
    printf("\nCognome: ");
    scanf("%s", contatto[ncont].cognome);

    contatto[ncont].tel = malloc(12 * sizeof(char*));
    printf("\nTelefono: ");
    scanf("%s", contatto[ncont].tel);
}
```

Comment: I first changed the argument passed in the function aggiungi in `aggiungi(&contatto, ncont);`, it worked, but with warning and note. In your way it works fine. But I don't understand what's happening when I create a simple array, and I pass it to a function as argument, but the function got the first argument as a pointer.

Comment: yes, function works with pointer, that is initialized from array (the address of the first item)

Answer (score 1):

You don't allocate memory for rubrica, you only allocate memory for a pointer to it. This provokes an invalid write memory access. You may try changing

```
   rubrica *contatto[MAX];
```

into

```
   rubrica contatto[MAX];
```

and

```
   aggiungi(*contatto, ncont);
```

into

```
   aggiungi(contatto, ncont);
```

Comment: My mistake is that I also changed the function argument!